# Custom fields sequelize , mysql and nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

i have a test and i have to create a table that has these fields :

`name , date , price , customField`

customField have a title and a list of key values.

example can have a product “House” with a customField called

`“House Fields” and this field has a list of key values such as “Type” => “Apartment”, “Rooms”=> 5 etc`

How can i implement this customField using mySQL and sequelize with nodejs
Note : i am using mySQL by xampp